# Setting a timeout of shell after running sudo su

Tags: ubuntu, shell, sudo

my question is about making shell sessions timeout after a set time of inactivity, even if `sudo su` has been used.

My attempt has been to edit the /etc/profile file and adding:

```
export TMOUT=600  
readonly TMOUT.
```

It works for my usual account, but if I type `sudo su`, the shell will no longer exit after the set time amount. My question is simply, how could I go about accomplishing my goal?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
visudo
```

find the defaults line and add

```
Defaults env_reset,timestamp_timeout=5
```

and also I believe your

```
 export TMOUT=600  
 readonly TMOUT.
```

must be added there also, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but as I understand it 

`Defaults env_reset,timestamp_timeout=5`

is a setting for how long after I run `sudo <command>`, that my privileges are escalated afterwards. 

What I am looking for is that after I run `sudo su` i want to automatically exit the state of escalated privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it, to last thru a sudo su,

In the /etc/profile.d add a file setting the timeout, e.g.

```
root@dlc-john2:/home/dlc# cat /etc/profile.d/autologout.sh 

TMOUT=7200
readonly TMOUT
export TMOUT
```

This will work for any login shell, then to have it last thru a sudo:

Add the following by editing the sudoers as root: 
sudo visudo

Add the line (usually at the top), adding TMOUT to
the list of vars to keep:

```
Defaults        env_keep+="TMOUT"
```

If your sudoers files uses an Include /etc/sudoers.d -- then you can create a file with the above there.

Hope this helps!